# What is the best way in WebMatrix to query WCF services?

Tags: wcf, json, razor, webmatrix

I have an ASP.Net project using the Razor view engine which currently queries various databases directly with WebMatrix.Data.Database.Open.

I'm trying to migrate all direct database access to Web Services using WCF so that I get consistent business logic.  In doing this, I have also enabled the WCF service to be "httpGetEnabled".  This allows me to use Excel Macros to query the same web service.

My question is, what is the best way to query these web services from a Razor/WebMatrix page?

Should I JSON enable my WCF service and use the WebMatrix JSON helper?  Or should I be using JQuery to get the xml?

I would assume the former would be the best way, but how do I JSON enable my WCF service?  I remember seeing a video that allowed me to specify an additional query parameter to the WCF request to get JSON, but I can't find it again.

Any thoughts or pointers in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

Kind regards.

---

Edit:

I've recently seen this on Stack Overflow :
[Client Side Binding using by Converting the WCF Services to JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5074603/client-side-binding-using-by-converting-the-wcf-services-to-json)

On following this, I went to the MSDN article referred to around WebHttpBehavior.  I have since added "automaticFormatSelectionEnabled=true" to the webHttp element in Web.config.  In addition, I added the following code which then allowed me to specify "format=json" as a query parameter:

```
string formatQueryStringValue = WebOperationContext.Current.IncomingRequest.UriTemplateMatch.QueryParameters["format"];
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(formatQueryStringValue))
{
    if (formatQueryStringValue.Equals("xml", System.StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
    {
        WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse.Format = WebMessageFormat.Xml;
    }
    else if (formatQueryStringValue.Equals("json", System.StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
    {
        WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse.Format = WebMessageFormat.Json;
    }
}
```

I now just need to work out how to use the WebMatrix JSON helper to get the results... Will update when I get some more information.

---

Edit 2

Hmm, I don't think that helped... Now I can get JSON from the webservice, but the JSON web helper only seems to help if you have some JSON data already.  I'm just not sure how to get that JSON data which I can then use the JSON Helper to convert it (decode) into a class.

So I guess my question now is, how do I get JSON data and then bridge that to WebMatrix/Razor for use in a WebGrid?

Comment: Do you want to call the service from the client or the server?

Comment: I don't really have a preference, I guess I just want to do what is considered best practice...

Comment: It completely depends on what you're trying to do.

Comment: Just trying to find the easiest way to query the web service to present data onto the page...  The web service is just returning xml at the moment, so I either need to enable it to return JSON so that I can use the web helper in WebMatrix; or I need to find a way to query the web service and enumerate the xml returned...

Comment: As an example, when I browse to the sevice help file: http://uklonapps1/services/ClientsWS/ClientsService.svc/help I get a list of operations, the only one currently is QueryClients which looks like this:  "http://uklonapps1/Services/ClientsWS/ClientsService.svc/QueryClients?companyname={COMPANYNAME}&firstname={FIRSTNAME}&lastname={LASTNAME}"

Answer (score 0):

From all I read you would want to know what is the best practice in this case if I am correct.

The best practice from what I know is to not make your website query through the wcf at all.

why ?
-Because their both located on your server... no point creating a connection again to just get data.
They should both have direct connection to the data which for you is webmatrix....
You would use WCF for other applications like a .exe you created which stores farm animals.

Extra note: you can add the WCF to your ASP.NEt project and both access same database which would be best case if you still require it.

Comment: While I agree Wcf is a bit overkill for this example. I'm not sure what you mean by their both on the server. Any request made by the webpage will not be made from the server, but from the clients computer.

Comment: Sorry if I ain't clear, kinda multi-tasking. What's the point of dividing the web page into requesting from 2 different routes ? It will just be harder for organizing all his code. Their both situated on the server, might as well access the one that has been giving all you gotten so far through the website.

Comment: Sorry for the delayed response.  My problem is that the web service already exists and has business logic which I don't want to replicate.  In addition, it also connects to a legacy database elsewhere.  Finally, what if I didn't have control over the web service?    I've added a Web Reference now in VS (which I'm not sure you can do in the WebMatrix interface), but now I'm getting an error that it couldn't find the endpoint in the Service Model... There must be an easier way...